# Can you tell me how to edit this java annotation mongodb correctly @Query("{ 'ask': ?0}")?

Tags: java, json, spring, mongodb

This annotation searches for a document. The document has an array with values. The annotation searches for matches in the array. If there is a match, the document is returned. But if there is no match, this annotation continues to work without returning anything. Spring returns the `java.lang error.NullPointerException: null`. The user's request is queued and the next one is queued as well. How do I return null from `@Query`?

```json
{
    "_id":{"$oid":"5fa6cdf065249ffc1282e880"},   
    "ask":["java",  
        "what is java",  
        "java is"],  
    "answer":"Java is a class-based, object-oriented programming language that is designed to have as few implementation dependencies as possible"
}
```

So I'm looking for

```java
@Repository
public interface PostRepository extends MongoRepository<Answer, String> {

    @Query("{ 'ask': ?0}")
    public Answer findAnswerByAsk(String ask);
}
```

````
```java
@Data
@Document(collection = "answer")
public class Answer{

    @Id
    private String id;
    @Field("ask")
    private String[] ask;
    @Field("answer")
    private String answer;
    @Field("keyWords")
    private String[] keyWords;

    public Answer(String[] ask, String answer, String[] keyWords) {
        this.ask = ask;
        this.answer = answer;
        this.keyWords = keyWords;
    }

    public Answer(){}

}
````

Comment: What does your `Answer` class look like? What is the full stacktrace?

Comment: I added the code of the Answer class to the description

Answer (score 0):

the problem was not in this, this record is 100% working, the problem was with the bean